# Where are python bytearrays used?

Tags: python, types

I recently came across the dataType called `bytearray` in python. Could someone provide scenarios where bytearrays are required?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

A `bytearray` is very similar to a regular python string (`str` in python2.x, `bytes` in python3) but with an important difference, whereas strings are *immutable*, `bytearray`s are mutable, a bit like a `list` of single character strings.

This is useful because some applications use byte sequences in ways that perform poorly with immutable strings.  When you are making lots of little changes in the middle of large chunks of memory, as in a database engine, or image library, strings perform quite poorly; since you have to make a copy of the whole (possibly large) string.  `bytearray`s have the advantage of making it possible to make that kind of change without making a copy of the memory first.

But this particular case is actually more the exception, rather than the rule.  Most uses involve comparing strings, or string formatting. For the latter, there's usually a copy anyway, so a mutable type would offer no advantage, and for the former, since immutable strings cannot change, you can calculate a `hash` of the string and compare that as a shortcut to comparing each byte in order, which is almost always a big win; and so it's the immutable type (`str` or `bytes`) that is the default; and `bytearray` is the exception when you need it's special features.

Comment: Moreover,a bytearray allows one to manipulate its elements as either numbers in the 0-256 range or one-char strings, just like it is done in C an dother derived languages. It is quite flexible in this respect.

Comment: Note that in python 2.x you were allowed to set the index of a bytearray using either an integer (e.g. `myarray[x] = 116) or a single string character (e.g. `myarray[x] = 't'`). In python 3.x you are *only* allowed to use integers; attempting to set a string value to an index of a bytearray will result in a TypeError.

Comment: +Jordan  Reiter +jsbueno it seems to me like your comments are contradictory; are you allowed to manipulate elements of a byte array as one-char strings or not?? (in Python 3.x, since I guess jsbueno's comment is meant for all Python versions?)

Comment: @HelloGoodbye: I hadn't noticed that about py3 before.  as you observe, using `bytearray[n]` requires items of type int.  You can still manipulate bytearrays in terms of "strings" by using slicing, although `foo[3] = 'x'` does not work, `foo[3:4] = b'x'` works fine.  You have to specify start and end positions for the replacement to work, and you must use a `bytes` value, a python3 `str` is not allowed.

Answer (score 59):

This answer has been shameless ripped off from [here](http://dabeaz.blogspot.com/2010/01/few-useful-bytearray-tricks.html)

#### Example 1: Assembling a message from fragments

Suppose you're writing some network code that is receiving a large message on a socket connection. If you know about sockets, you know that the `recv()` operation doesn't wait for all of the data to arrive. Instead, it merely returns what's currently available in the system buffers. Therefore, to get all of the data, you might write code that looks like this:

```
# remaining = number of bytes being received (determined already)
msg = b""
while remaining > 0:
    chunk = s.recv(remaining)    # Get available data
    msg += chunk                 # Add it to the message
    remaining -= len(chunk)
```

The only problem with this code is that concatenation (`+=`) has horrible performance. Therefore, a common performance optimization in Python 2 is to collect all of the chunks in a list and perform a join when you're done. Like this:

```
# remaining = number of bytes being received (determined already)
msgparts = []
while remaining > 0:
    chunk = s.recv(remaining)    # Get available data
    msgparts.append(chunk)       # Add it to list of chunks
    remaining -= len(chunk)  
msg = b"".join(msgparts)          # Make the final message
```

Now, here's a third solution using a `bytearray`:

```
# remaining = number of bytes being received (determined already)
msg = bytearray()
while remaining > 0:
    chunk = s.recv(remaining)    # Get available data
    msg.extend(chunk)            # Add to message
    remaining -= len(chunk)
```

Notice how the `bytearray` version is really clean. You don't collect parts in a list and you don't perform that cryptic join at the end. Nice.

Of course, the big question is whether or not it performs. To test this out, I first made a list of small byte fragments like this:

```
chunks = [b"x"*16]*512
```

I then used the timeit module to compare the following two code fragments:

```
# Version 1
msgparts = []
for chunk in chunks:
    msgparts.append(chunk)
msg = b"".join(msgparts)
```

```
#Version 2
msg = bytearray()
for chunk in chunks:
    msg.extend(chunk)
```

When tested, version 1 of the code ran in 99.8s whereas version 2 ran in 116.6s (a version using `+=` concatenation takes 230.3s by comparison). So while performing a join operation is still faster, it's only faster by about 16%. Personally, I think the cleaner programming of the `bytearray` version might make up for it.

#### Example 2: Binary record packing

This example is an slight twist on the last example. Suppose you had a large Python list of integer (x,y) coordinates. Something like this:
`points = [(1,2),(3,4),(9,10),(23,14),(50,90),...]`
Now, suppose you need to write that data out as a binary encoded file consisting of a 32-bit integer length followed by each point packed into a pair of 32-bit integers. One way to do it would be to use the struct module like this:

```
import struct
f = open("points.bin","wb")
f.write(struct.pack("I",len(points)))
for x,y in points:
    f.write(struct.pack("II",x,y))
f.close()
```

The only problem with this code is that it performs a large number of small `write()` operations. An alternative approach is to pack everything into a `bytearray` and only perform one write at the end. For example:

```
import struct
f = open("points.bin","wb")
msg = bytearray()
msg.extend(struct.pack("I",len(points))
for x,y in points:
    msg.extend(struct.pack("II",x,y))
f.write(msg)
f.close()
```

Sure enough, the version that uses `bytearray` runs much faster. In a simple timing test involving a list of 100000 points, it runs in about half the time as the version that makes a lot of small writes.

#### Example 3: Mathematical processing of byte values

The fact that bytearrays present themselves as arrays of integers makes it easier to perform certain kinds of calculations. In a recent embedded systems project, I was using Python to communicate with a device over a serial port. As part of the communications protocol, all messages had to be signed with a Longitudinal Redundancy Check (LRC) byte. An LRC is computed by taking an XOR across all of the byte values.
Bytearrays make such calculations easy. Here's one version:

```
message = bytearray(...)     # Message already created
lrc = 0
for b in message:
    lrc ^= b
message.append(lrc)          # Add to the end of the message
```

Here's a version that increases your job security:
`message.append(functools.reduce(lambda x,y:x^y,message))`
And here's the same calculation in Python 2 without `bytearray`s:

```
message = "..."       # Message already created
lrc = 0
for b in message:
    lrc ^= ord(b)
message += chr(lrc)        # Add the LRC byte
```

Personally, I like the `bytearray` version. There's no need to use `ord()` and you can just append the result at the end of the message instead of using concatenation.

Here's another cute example. Suppose you wanted to run a `bytearray` through a simple XOR-cipher. Here's a one-liner to do it:

```
>>> key = 37
>>> message = bytearray(b"Hello World")
>>> s = bytearray(x ^ key for x in message)
>>> s
bytearray(b'm@IIJ\x05rJWIA')
>>> bytearray(x ^ key for x in s)
bytearray(b"Hello World")
>>>
```

[Here](http://python.mirocommunity.org/video/1573/pycon-2010-mastering-python-3-) is a link to the presentation

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been wondering for a while why the standard library uses the `b''.join(chunks)` approach (and have been too lazy, on the other hand, to do benchmarks myself).

Comment: Did he copy you, you copy him or you copy yourself? :) http://dabeaz.blogspot.com/2010/01/few-useful-bytearray-tricks.html

Answer (score 5):

If you look at the documentation for [`bytearray`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/functions.html#bytearray), it says:

> Return a new array of bytes. The bytearray type is a mutable sequence of integers in the range 0 <= x < 256.

In contrast, the documentation for [`bytes`](http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/functions.html#bytes) says:

> Return a new “bytes” object, which is an immutable sequence of integers in the range 0 <= x < 256. bytes is an immutable version of bytearray – it has the same non-mutating methods and the same indexing and slicing behaviors.

As you can see, the primary distinction is mutability. `str` methods that "change" the string actually return a new string with the desired modification.  Whereas `bytearray` methods that change the sequence *actually change the sequence*.

You would prefer using `bytearray`, if you are editing a large object (e.g. an image's pixel buffer) through its binary representation and you want the modifications to be done in-place for efficiency.

Comment: I don't think this is necessarily true re: `bytearray` methods, many of which are described as "returning a copy of the object/seq." (as of 3.6). I'm not certain but I think the main benefit is being able to access potentially large buffers without any intermediate copying (into python objects, probably mostly strings?); so for mutability I think the benefit comes from indexing/slicing instead of methods that actually mutate 'bytearray's, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Wikipedia provides an example of [XOR cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_cipher) using Python's bytearrays (docstrings reduced):

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

from os import urandom

def vernam_genkey(length):
    """Generating a key"""
    return bytearray(urandom(length))

def vernam_encrypt(plaintext, key):
    """Encrypting the message."""
    return bytearray([ord(plaintext[i]) ^ key[i] for i in xrange(len(plaintext))])

def vernam_decrypt(ciphertext, key):
    """Decrypting the message"""
    return bytearray([ciphertext[i] ^ key[i] for i in xrange(len(ciphertext))])

def main():
    myMessage = """This is a topsecret message..."""
    print 'message:',myMessage
    key = vernam_genkey(len(myMessage))
    print 'key:', str(key)
    cipherText = vernam_encrypt(myMessage, key)
    print 'cipherText:', str(cipherText)
    print 'decrypted:', vernam_decrypt(cipherText,key)

    if vernam_decrypt(vernam_encrypt(myMessage, key),key)==myMessage:
        print ('Unit Test Passed')
    else:
        print('Unit Test Failed - Check Your Python Distribution')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: you could write: `vernam_encrypt = vernam_decrypt = lambda data, key: bytearray(a^b for a, b in zip(*map(bytearray, [data, key])))`

Comment: `print(binascii.hexlify(key).decode())` to print the key as a hex string. To convert it back: `key = binascii.unhexlify(hex_string)`.