# Difference between bytearray and list

Tags: python, python-2.7

What is the difference between `bytearray` and for example, a `list` or `tuple`?

As the name suggests, `bytearray` must be an `array` that carries `byte` objects. 
In python, it seems that `bytes` and `str` are treated equally

```
>>> bytes
<type 'str'>
```

So, what is the difference? 
Also, if you print a `bytearray`, the result is pretty weird

```
>>> v = bytearray([200, 201])
>>> print v
ÈÉ
```

It seems that it transforms the integer in `chr(integer)` , is that right? What is the use of a `bytearray` then?

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099145/where-are-python-bytearrays-used

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are correct in some way: In Python 2, `bytes` is synonymous with the `str` type. This is because originally, there was no `bytes` object, there was only `str` and `unicode` (the latter being for unicode string, i.e. having multi-byte capabilities). When Python 3 came, they changed the whole string things and made unicode the default Python 3 `str` type, and they added `bytes` as the type for raw byte sequences (making it equivalent to Python 2’s `str` object).

So while in Python 3 you differ between `str` and `bytes`, the corresponding types in Python 2 are `unicode` and `str`.

Now what makes the `bytearray` type interesting is that it’s mutable. All string and byte sequences above are immutable, so with every change, you are creating a new object. But you can modify `bytearray` objects, making them interesting for various purposes where you need to modify individual bytes in a sequence.

Comment: The other thing that makes `bytearray` interesting (compared to Python's `str`, not so much compared to Python 3's `bytes`) is that it's a bit ambiguous what it's an array of. In Python 2, sometimes bytes are characters, and sometimes they're small numbers. if ` = bytearray([97,98,99])`, `repr(b)` gives you `bytearray(b'abc')`. But `b[0]` gives you `97`. This can be confusing if you're used to `str` hiding that from you and forcing you to call `ord` and `chr` (`'abc'[0]` is `'a'`, not 97).