# What is usage of binary sequence type in python?

Tags: python

Python has many types.
What is usage of binary sequence types in python?
There are 3 binary sequence types:

1. `bytes`
2. `bytearray`
3. `MemoryView`

What are they use for?

Comment: This question is probably too broad for the Q&A format of StackOverflow. But have a look at this talk by Brandon Rhodes where he demonstrates some use cases for these three types: [Oh, Come On Who Needs Bytearrays - PyCon 2015](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z9Hmys8ojno)

Comment: @LukasGraf Nice talk

Answer (score 1):

Actually all of these three types' use were discussed already:

1) About `bytes` look at the answers to the question [the bytes type in python 2.7 and PEP-358](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5901706/the-bytes-type-in-python-2-7-and-pep-358)

2) About `bytearray` usage look at the answers to the question [Where are python bytearrays used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9099145/where-are-python-bytearrays-used)

3) About `MemoryView` look at good answers to the questions
[When should a memoryview be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845418/when-should-a-memoryview-be-used)
and [What exactly is the point of memoryview in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18655648/what-exactly-is-the-point-of-memoryview-in-python?lq=1)